# Methods for preventing flicker when navigating between pages

Tags: asp.net, ajax, master-pages, flicker

I must say that I am exhausted from searching for the last 3 hours. I know this issue has been investigated before, and I have tried several solutions to no avail.

I have an asp.net website with a master page which contains a top navigation menu for navigating between different pages. I would like to prevent the flickering when I navigate between these pages. I'll just make a note that this flicker occurs in IE and Chrome while it does not occur in firefox.

The methods I have tried:

- using the several meta tag solutions, such as: `<meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="Alpha(opacity=100)" />`
- wrapping the contentplaceholder in the master page with an updatepanel
- wrapping just the navigation menu in the update panel.

None of these methods is working and I really don't think that using iframes is a good solution for my case.

Are there any other solutions ?

Comment: What was in the update panel originally?

Answer (score 0):

This is known as FOUC (flash of unstyled content) and can be caused by @import CSS statements. In some cases, it was browser specific and doesn't occur as often these days:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content

Sometimes this can be fixed by simply making sure your CSS is loaded first:

https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/how-to-prevent-flash-of-unstyled-content-on-your-websites/

Comment: This scenario isn't actually happening in my case, I see a white blank page, not a FOUC, where the content is there but it's just not styled...

Comment: Why are you using an update panel? Specifically, why would you put navigation in it?

Comment: The links are dead

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem was that I had a lot of javascript files in the head section, so when I moved it to the bottom, just before the closing body tag, the flickering was mitigated substantially.
This solution can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722611/page-load-white-flash-inbetween-pages) question on stack overflow.